# java code for solr geolocation indexing

Tags: solr, solrj

I am using solr for fixing my indexing and searching feature and a beginner to solr.
I actually want to index the geolocation into solr index and also want to make queries on it so went through some articles,
http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SpatialSearch
And exactly some schema type are present in my schema.xml.

Now my question is I want to write a java code to index the geolocation while indexing it for dynamic geolocation fields. So how to write it and is there any sample java code for indexing it. I looked for it but didn't found any so please if anybody can help me with it.

I also understand that when indexing we would need to write some thing like :

```
document.addField(myDynLocFld+"_p", val));
```

If using this approach what should be val an instance of location object with both lat and lng value embedded in it. So how to counter this or is there any diferent approach in solr java for this?

Thanking in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Check this sample of code,

```
// Store the index in memory:
//Directory directory = new RAMDirectory();
// To store an index on disk
Directory directory = FSDirectory.open("/tmp/testindex");
IndexWriterConfig config = new IndexWriterConfig(Version.LUCENE_CURRENT, analyzer);
IndexWriter iwriter = new IndexWriter(directory, config);
Document doc = new Document();
String text = "This is the text to be indexed.";
doc.add(new Field("fieldname", text, TextField.TYPE_STORED));
iwriter.addDocument(doc);
iwriter.close();
```

For more details check [Lucene APIs](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_3_1/core/overview-summary.html).

Comment: this code snippet is meant for lucene to index a single document  into the indexes. I want java code to add the geolcation details to SolrInputDocument of solr and to index and then fetch them.